# bash, get current time in milliseconds since midnight

Tags: bash, time, milliseconds

Is there a way to get the current milliseconds past midnight in bash? And if there is a way to do it entirely in bash, how good or bad is the precision of that timestamp?

Comment: Check [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/151109/how-do-i-get-current-unix-time-in-milliseconds-using-bash).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get today's midnight with:

```
date -d 'today 00:00:00'
```

in UNIX stamp:

```
date -d 'today 00:00:00' "+%s"
```

So if you want to get the difference, do:

```
midnight=$(date -d 'today 00:00:00' "+%s")
now=$(date "+%s")
diff_mills=$(( ($now - $midnight) * 1000 ))
```

as `%s` indicates seconds, we have to `*1000` to get milliseconds.

---

With `%N` (nanoseconds):

```
midnight=$(date -d 'today 00:00:00' "+%s.%N")
now=$(date "+%s.%N")
diff_mills=$(echo "( $now - $midnight ) * 1000" | bc)
```

Comment: And to get a better precision, you can use `+%N` to get the nanoseconds.

Comment: Sure. Just added for nanoseconds. As it is 10^-9, we have to /10^6 at the end.

Comment: Er, no. `%N` is nanoseconds in the current second. So absolute time would be `%s.%N` (`%N` is helpfully zero padded).

Comment: Uhms, I had to investigate how to do it. `$(( ))` does not work for float, so I am using `bc` now. Should be ok now, @bobbogo. Thanks for indicating!

Comment: And to convert back to int at the end, something like this can be used: INT=${FLOAT/\.*}

Answer (score 3):

You can also use mod instead of an explicit date difference. So for example, with 1 second resolution:

```
millis_since_midnight=$[1000 * ( ( `date "+%s"` - 28800 ) % 86400 )]
```

Note that 28800 is the PST offset from UTC in seconds. This kludge was useful for me on systems like OSX that have BSD time and thus lack the ability to specify `--date 'today 00:00:00'`.